# Apex chart instance variable not defined error during update of charts using updateOptions

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, charts, javascript-objects, apexcharts

I am using Apexcharts for creating charts in my application. onload all first data is loading perfectly. but on applying filter i need to refresh or update the charts with the new data from filter, I tried using updateOptions method but its showing the chart instance variable is undefined. on update the variable is showing undefined, please help and thanks in advance.

My html and js codes are below.

**HTML Code
**
This is the div where graph is rendering

````
<div class="col-md-4">

              <!-- PIE CHART -->
              <div class="card card-primary">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h3 class="card-title">HSE Incidents Statistics YTD</h3>

                  <div class="card-tools">
                    
                  <select class="" name="yearFilter" id="yearFilter" onchange="drawchart1();">
                    <?php 
                      $year_start  = 2020;
                      $year_end = date('Y'); // current Year
                      $user_selected_year = date('Y'); // user date of birth year
                      for ($i_year = $year_start; $i_year <= $year_end; $i_year++) {
                        $selected = ($user_selected_year == $i_year ? ' selected' : ''); ?>
                          <option <?= $selected ?> value="<?php echo $i_year ?>"><?php echo $i_year ?></option>
                      <?php
                        
                      }   
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="maximize"><i class="fas fa-expand"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.card-tools -->
                </div>
                <div class="card-body" id="chartReport1">
                  <div class="chartjs-size-monitor">
                    <div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand">
                      <div class=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink">
                      <div class=""></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div id="hse-incidents-ytd" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.card -->

            </div>```




**JS CODE**


```$(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $root_url ?>/data-hse-incidents.php",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          var month = [];
          var count = [];

          for (var i in data) {
            month.push(data[i].month);
            count.push(data[i].count);
          }

          var options = {
            series: [{
              name: 'Total Count',
              data: count,
            }],
            chart: {
              type: 'bar',
              height: 300
            },
            plotOptions: {
              bar: {
                horizontal: false,
                columnWidth: '30px',
                endingShape: 'rounded',
                dataLabels: {
                  position: 'top', // top, center, bottom
                },
              },
            },
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              offsetY: -20,
              style: {
                fontSize: '12px',
                colors: ["#304758"]
              }
            },
            stroke: {
              show: true,
              width: 2,
              colors: ['transparent']
            },
            xaxis: {
              categories: month,
              title: {
                text: 'Month'
              }
            },
            yaxis: {
              title: {
                text: 'Total Count'
              }
            },
            fill: {
              opacity: 1
            },
            tooltip: {
              y: {
                formatter: function(val) {
                  return val
                }
              }
            }
          };

          var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#hse-incidents-ytd"), options);
          chart.render();

        },
        error: function(data) {

        }
      });
      
    });
  function updateChart1() {

      var filter_year = $('#yearFilter').val();
      alert(filter_year);// working
      $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $root_url ?>/data-hse-incidents.php?y="+filter_year,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
              
            var month = [];
            var count = [];
            for (var i in data) {
              month.push(data[i].month);
              count.push(data[i].count);
            }
            alert(count); // working
            
            chart.updateOptions({ // error occurring here
                xaxis: {
                  categories: month,
                },
                series: [{
                    data: count,
                }],
            })
      },
      error: function(data) {}
      });
}

   function drawchart1() {
      updateChart1();
      
     }
````

[Image of error when I change the filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfpNh.png)

i need to update or refresh the chart with new data , data is coming correctly from the api , its not loading into the chart when filter is applied that's the issue. first load of chart is working fine.

Comment: You *declared* the variable `chart` inside the inner function `success` of the first `ajax` call. As such, it is not accessible to the second function. You have to move the *declaration* `var chart;` to a scope that is common to both functions (outside both functions, to the top of the script); and you may keep the *initialization* `chart = new ApexCharts...` (without `var`) where it is.

Comment: Thanks for the response. but the data for creating the chart is getting from that ajax , so how can i make this variable available for both the function.? can you suggest me any method. @kikon

Comment: My previous message contains a solution: (1) add a `var chart;` line immediately after the `<script>` (outside of the functions) and (2) delete the `var` in front the `chart`where it is now in your code (inside the first function). Thus you make the variable global, accessible to both functions, keeping its initialization where it is, in the first function.

Comment: i tried that solution , but its still showing same error , undefined chart variable

Comment: Please take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/26ae74qw/) with simulated data around your code

Comment: @kikon is right, even though we should avoid global variables as much as possible. I recommend you to read [this article about code organization with jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/concepts/).

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle , you can paste that fiddle as your answer for this question @kikon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @kikon, you mentioned why the variable was  not getting outside.

here is how i resolved that issue.

```
var chart, chart2,chart3,chart4,chart5,chart6,chart7,chart8,chart9,chart10,LineGraph,LineGraph1;
 // fucntion to load the ajax result
    
jQuery.extend({
    getValues: function(url) {
        // alert()
        var result = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'get',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                result = data;
            }
        });
    return result;
    }
});
```

// fucntion to load the ajax result

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var results = $.getValues("<?php echo $root_url ?>/data-hse-incidents.php");
var month = [];
var count = [];

  for (var i in results) {
    month.push(results[i].month);
    count.push(results[i].count);
  }

  var options = {
    series: [{
      name: 'Total Count',
      data: count,
    }],
    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      height: 300
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        horizontal: false,
        columnWidth: '30px',
        endingShape: 'rounded',
        dataLabels: {
          position: 'top', // top, center, bottom
        },
      },
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      offsetY: -20,
      style: {
        fontSize: '12px',
        colors: ["#304758"]
      }
    },
    stroke: {
      show: true,
      width: 2,
      colors: ['transparent']
    },
    xaxis: {
      categories: month,
      title: {
        text: 'Month'
      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Total Count'
      }
    },
    fill: {
      opacity: 1
    },
    tooltip: {
      y: {
        formatter: function(val) {
          return val
        }
      }
    }
  };

  chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#hse-incidents-ytd"), options);
  chart.render();
  
});

function updateChart1() {

    var filter_year = $('#yearFilter').val();
    // alert(filter_year);
    var results_updated = $.getValues("<?php echo $root_url ?>/data-hse-incidents.php?y="+filter_year);
    var month = [];
      var count = [];
      for (var i in results_updated) {
          month.push(results_updated[i].month);
          count.push(results_updated[i].count);
      }

    chart.updateOptions({
              xaxis: {
                categories: month,
              },
              series: [{
                  data: count,
              }],
          });
    }$('#yearFilter').change(function () {
  updateChart1();  });
```